# How can I change the passing percentage for code coverage?

Tags: bamboo, clover

I have Clover enabled in Bamboo, but the tester is failing because I don't have sufficient coverage.

I want to lower the passing coverage percent, but I don't see anywhere to set that.

How can I lower the passing coverage percentage in Bamboo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in maven-clover2-plugin a configuration of targetPercentage. You can also specify excluded classes

```
<configuration>
  <targetPercentage>60%</targetPercentage>
    <excludes>
      <exclude> myPackage/AppConfig.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```